# What is a strict definition of U-shaped relationship?

Tags: regression, references, terminology, nonlinear-regression, definition

I now have seen several papers that analyze U-shaped or inverse U-shaped relations among variables (in a regression framework). The general understanding I have from there is that it is a specific type of a non-linear relationship that we can all easily visualize.

However, I am a bit confused about how exactly people mathematically define U-shaped regression functions. Suppose for simplicity there is only regressor $x$.

Does having U-shaped regression function mean the regression function is convex and decreasing in $x$ up to some point $c$ and then after $c$ is convex and increasing in $x$?

Or does it simply mean that the regression function is decreasing in $x$ up to some point $c$ and then after $c$ is increasing in $x$?

Comment: Different authors may have different definitions--should the relation be continuous? Differentiable? Convex? The most general definition consistent with the idea of "increasing then decreasing" or "decreasing then increasing" is: A map $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ with $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is "U-shaped" means there exists a decomposition of $A=B\cup C$ where (1) every element of $B$ is less than or equal to every element of $C$; (2) $f$ is monotonic on both $B$ and $C$; (3) the images $f(B)$ and $f(C)$ have at least two values each; and (4) the directions of monotonicity of $f$ differ on $B$ and $C$.

Comment: @whuber This is exactly what I am looking for -- if there is a general agreement on how to define it....

Comment: I couldn't attest to a general agreement--and I'm sure that many authors would object that my definition is broader than they intended.  That's why I have left it as a comment.

Comment: I don't think "U-shaped" is a mathematically well-defined term; there is no universally accepted definition and I don't think you should be looking for one. I changed the first two sentences of my answer to stress that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer to your question (as stated elsewhere) is that
there is no single mathematical definition of a U-shape. The comment by @whuber is the
best general definition that I have seen.

I do research on tests of U-shapes and for my presentation I have a slide with the title
"What does a U mean to you?", meaning that it is subjective what people mean by
the term "U-shape". The most important thing is that when you use the term
"U-shape", you define exactly what *you* mean by it, without assuming that
others will know what you mean.

Since you specified the case of only one regressor, I'll focus on that. I've
seen the following definitions used in various articles:

- A U-shape is a quadratic.
- A U-shape means convexity (for an application along these lines, see Van Landeghem's 2012 "A test for the convexity of human well-being over the life cycle: Longitudinal evidence from a 20-year panel").
- A U-shape is a function with weighted average derivative negative until a point, and weighted average derivative positive after that point (see Uri Simonsohn's [Two-Lines: The First Valid Test of U-Shaped Relationships](http://datacolada.org/62)).
- A U-shape is a function with exactly one turning point. This corresponds to a function that is quasi-convex but not monotone.

One complication that comes up is what if the turning point is close to the
ends of the range of the x variable? Should we still consider such a function a
U-shape? In my opinion, such a discussion should be had when you define what a
U-shape means to you for your application, and when you specify your null
hypothesis.

The definition I use in my paper, [Non-Parametric Testing of U-Shaped Relationships](https://ssrn.com/abstract=2905833), is the following:

Let $m(x)$ be the regression function and let $S\left(X\right)$ be the support of $X$. For a specified set $A_{0}\subset S\left(X\right)$, we are interested in testing the following:

$$\begin{align*}
H_{0}\colon & \exists a\in A_{0}\mbox{ st }\forall x\in S\left(X\right)\\
 & m^{'}\left(x\right)\left(x-a\right)\ge0\\
\text{versus}\\H_{A}\colon & \forall a\in A_{0},\,\exists x\in S\left(X\right)\mbox{ st}\\
 & m^{'}\left(x\right)\left(x-a\right)<0
\end{align*}$$

For example, in an application I test for a U-shape of life satisfaction in age
from age 20 to 70, where the turning point is between ages 30 and 60. Arbitrary
decisions are necessary with this proposed framework. The important thing is to be open
about them and check how sensitive results are to changes (and to challenge others to do the same).

In addition to stating the null hypothesis, as always you should state the
assumptions you rely on. For example, a common assumption is that the
regression function is either U-shaped on monotone. See, for example, Lind and
Mehlum's 2009 "With or Without U? The Appropriate Test for a U-Shaped
Relationship", where they propose an improvement on the vanilla OLS quadratic test by testing that the derivative of a specified functional
form is negative at the beginning of the range, and positive at the end.

An additional point to consider is: Do you want a test that rejects the null hypothesis because of a small violation of U-shapedness? If yes, consider the R package [qmutest](https://github.com/scottkosty/qmutest), which implements a non-parametric tests based on splines of the null hypotheses that the regression function is quasi-convex, and separately that it is monotone. If you do not want a test that gives inference against a U-shape because of a small violation, Uri's two lines test might be best if you want to test that a regression function is mostly decreasing and then mostly increasing.

Since your question was about the use of the term "U-shape" and the
definition, I find it relevant to list some terms here that are used often to
refer to the same thing that "U-shape" and "inverted U-shape" are used to refer
to: "valley-shaped", "trough-shaped", "hill-shaped", "unimodal",
"single-peaked", and "bell-shaped". There is no inherent reason why "U-shape"
is a better term than the others, but its use seems to have caught on.

I'm working on a general R package that will just be an interface to
specific R packages (such as qmutest) that test for U-shaped relationships however they choose to
define them. The goal will be to help users compare different tests and to
think hard about the exact null hypothesis they want to test, and which
assumptions they are prepared to make.

Comment: +1. I am a bit confused by this sentence: "Do you want a test that rejects the null hypothesis because of a small violation of U-shapedness?" I assume that the null is that there is no U-shapedness, so that a sufficiently small p-value were an evidence of U-shapedness, is that correct?

Comment: (I am glad to see that you favourably mention Uri's paper: I mentioned it in my answer here and it was heavily criticized in the comments.)

Comment: @amoeba the nulls of the qmutest package are quasi-convexity and monotonicity (corresponding to the R functions `cbquasi` and `cbmono`). Combined, the tests give inference about U-shapes. Indeed this is different from the OLS quadratic specification and Uri's two lines test. I made edits to add information on the null hypotheses.

Comment: (+1) Very nice, thoughtful, authoritative overview.  Welcome to our site!

Comment: I am sorry I still don't understand this bit that I quoted above: "Do you want a test that rejects the null hypothesis because of a small violation of U-shapedness?" Can you please explain what this means? Are you asking if one wants a test that rejects the null [of no U-shape; i.e. a test that concludes that there is a U-shape] if there is "a small violation of U-shapedness" i.e. if there actually is no U-shape but almost a U-shape? I am pretty confused by what you mean here.

Comment: @amoeba When I use "U-shape" I'm referring to definition 4 above (a function with exactly one turning point). For my test, the null is U-shapedness. What I mean is that asymptotically the null of U-shapedness will be rejected if there is any violation of U-shapedness in the underlying regression function (e.g. there are two turning points). This is not the case for Uri's test because the two lines test is about the average derivative. So there can be wiggles without necessarily leading to asymptotic inference against U-shapes.

Comment: @amoeba As an example, see the function labeled "sin" in Figure 2 of my paper. I believe (although I have not checked) that the two lines test would give asymptotic inference suggesting that "sin" is a U-shape, even though it has three turning points.

Comment: @scottkosty, any progress on the package you reference at the bottom of your post?

Comment: @Parseltongue unfortunately I've made zero progress directly on that package. I would like to work on better non-parametric methods before that general package. It's only indirectly related, but I've been working on a paper for a new quasi-convexity restriction method (https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.01038). However, it will take time for that work to translate into U-shapes. Probably I won't work on the general R package still for another couple of years.

Answer (score 7):

**"U-shaped relationship" is not a mathematically precise term and there is no universally accepted definition. It *usually* means that the relationship is first decreasing and then increasing, or vice versa.**

In other words, it means that the relationship is not monotonic (non-monotonic), but instead has exactly one extremum (maximum or minimum). In computer science this is [sometimes called "bitonic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter).

Uri Simonsohn has recently written an interesting paper about testing U-shaped relationships. See his preprint [Two-Lines: A Valid Alternative to the Invalid Testing of U-Shaped Relationships with Quadratic Regressions](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3021690) which is very readable and amusing. Here is how the paper starts:

> Is there such thing as too many options, virtues, or examples in an opening 
>   sentence? Researchers are often interested in these types of questions, in assessing if the effect of $x$ on $y$ is positive for low values of $x$, but negative for high values of $x$. For ease of exposition, I refer to all
>   such relationships as 'u-shaped,' whether they are symmetric 
>   or not (i.e., U or J shaped), and whether the effect of $x$ on $y$ goes from negative to positive or vice versa (i.e., U or inverted-U).

This supports the definition I gave above.

---

For a short overview of Uri's paper, one can read his DataColada post [Two-lines: The First Valid Test of U-Shaped Relationships](http://datacolada.org/62). The main point is that using quadratic regression  to test the presence of a U-shaped relationship is **very very wrong.** Apparently quadratic fits are often used in some fields to argue in favor of a U-shaped relationship (i.e. t-test for the quadratic term is taken to be the test of U-shape-ness); this is troubling.

Here is the key figure:

[image: U-shaped relationships]

**Update:** There is some criticism of Uri's paper in the comments. I would like to stress that he never suggests that discontinuous two-line fits are supposed to model the data well (or that the jump at the discontinuity has some physical meaning). No. This fit is used for *the sole purpose* of providing a statistical test of U-shape-ness.

Of course I agree with @FrankHarrell that it makes much more sense to use a spline model to fit such nonlinear relationships. But splines do not provide a test of U-shape-ness, whereas Uri's two-line fit does.

Comment: I'd say that a quadratic curve points towards, in the first place, a varying slope. Which I believe is a very very good way (or at least easy way, in many circumstances) to check that. Yet a very very bad way to represent the (true) underlying relationship, especially the, if you could say, U-ness of a relationship.

Comment: My point puts nuance on the bad bad behavior of quadratic fits. In the end, by some shift of variables, we could make any "L" relation ship into "U" shape. This does not make the critique on the sloppy language about U shaped relationships and related (symmetric) quadratic fits less sloppy. However it may tell that the critique on (indeed ridiculous) conclusions, can be at some times pedantic. In the case of the two images from Sterling and Swaab, the U-shape might be ridiculous, and strictly speaking there is more like an L/J-shape, however the U shape conveys the story to non professionals.

Comment: The two-line fits in his examples do not even have zero-order continuity, which is almost impossible in real relationships between continuous variables.  The quadratic fit seems to be better than D.  But all of this is why we use regression splines to fit smooth relationships; they relax the assumptions of quadratic shapes.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Actually there is a very good reason why they don't enforce continuity of the two-line fits, see Figure 9 in the linked preprint. They never claim that these two-line linear fits are supposed to model underlying relationship well; the fits are only used for the purpose of testing U-shape-ness. I agree that splines make a lot more sense in a more general situation.

Comment: I just read it.  He says 'forcing two lines to connect introduces bias'.  What a strange argument.  Allowing them not to connect introduces impossibilities.  I find the whole two-line argument weak.  It seems to just be avoiding splines.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Well, I imagine it's hard (if at all possible) to come up with a p-value for U-shape-ness based on a splines model. I guess in many cases it's enough to build a good splines model and then just eyeball it to see if there is any evidence of U-shape-ness. And you don't like p-values anyway. So that's fine. But this paper is trying to develop some instrument for the researchers that want to compute a p-value for U-shape-ness; and this instrument should not have obviously ridiculous false positive rate like quadratic term in regression does... At least that's my understanding.

Comment: I don't see his arguments are strong.  Splines are more likely to fit; why stop at bilinear or even present it seriously?  With splines, testing for association (flatness) and nonlinearity are trivial.  Testing for non-monotonicity is a challenge; would like to see a reference on that.  Regarding just testing for nonlinearity (but ignoring accuracy of predictions) quadratics do a pretty decent job.  The two-lines method is very dependent on where you place the discontinuity.

Comment: @Frank "Non-monotonicity" is a good term! Just look at the Sterling et al paper referenced in the figure; abstract says that they "observed a quadratic association, which indicated that ideological moderates were more susceptible to bullshit than ideological extremists" -- which is just bullshit. Two-lines-test would allow them to test non-monotonicity and see that it's not even significant at 0.05 level. The two-lines paper discusses optimizing discontinuity in some detail, but I don't recall the details. It would certainly be nice to have some test for non-monotonicity with splines, I agree.

Comment: Agree with @FrankHarrell - I think a much more natural way to model this kind of relationship (on the premise of just trying to capture the first increase then decrease) is a Bayesian Latent model, which you model the change point as a latent variable and two linear models for before and after this latent change point. And the two intercept of the linear models should link together so at the change point they share the same value. Allowing two lines to disconnect is not appropriate.

Comment: Even though I love Bayesian modeling I'm not convinced that the thought experiment of imagining a change point is the straightest way to go.  I would rather see a flexible smooth fit with a prior distribution for the degree of non-monotonicity.

Comment: @CharlesLao Just look at the Figure 9 in the linked paper please. If you do what you suggest and if the model is badly misspecified (like shown on that figure), then you can get what looks like a significant increase-decrease breakpoint whereas in reality there is no non-monotonicity.

Comment: @amoeba I dont think that really qualified as an example of "first increase then decrease" :-) If your data looks like that why not just fit it with a logarithm function?

Comment: @CharlesLao No reason, but the point is that some people *in practice* obviously don't look at their data at all (or maybe don't think at all?): see two examples on the figure that I reproduced in this answer. I think you don't fully appreciate where Uri is coming from; this paper is supposed to suggest a specific actionable alternative to the moronic practice of fitting a quadratic and using the t-test for the quadratic term as a test for non-monotonicity.